# AG Grid Styling on select dropdown for Date filter

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I am trying to style the drop down for AG Grid, but seem to have set it to transparent somewhere. I have a theme similar to

```
.ag-theme-material-dark {
  @include ag-theme-material(
   ....
```

My problem is that the select drop down on the date filter is transparent. Any ideas how to override this?

I have set the background to blue to test

[image]

When you click this the dropdown is transparent see below:

[image]